# $.extend() in .each() function, strange behavior?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-plugins

This is the end of my plugin as wrapper of Highcharts api. I'm using `extend()` inside `each()` function to set the property `chart.renderTo` to the current object `id` attribute.

**But** this is not working. Output of `console.log($(this).attr('id'))` is correct but `console.log(opt.chartOptions)` shows only the last id (*chart2*) as `chart.renderTo` property.

**Am i missing something about `$.extend()` jQuery function?**

```
    var chartOptions = {}; // Plain option object

    return this.each(function() { // Each div

        console.log($(this).attr('id')); // Output: "chart1", "chart2"
        $.extend(opt.chartOptions, { chart : {renderTo : $(this).attr('id') } });
        console.log(opt.chartOptions); // Ops! chart.renderTo is always "chart2"

        $.ajax({
            url : opt.url,
            type : 'POST',
            data : opt.data,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                $.extend(data, opt.chartOptions); // Merge data from server
                new Highcharts.Chart(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `opt.chartOptions` is a variable scoped locally in your plugin function. If that is true, then what you're doing here is trying to extend `opt.chartOptions` for each of the `div`s in the wrapper context.

Everytime you're iterating through the extend (e.g. `$.extend(foo,bar)`), jQuery extends `foo` with the properties of `bar`. I'm sure you're aware of that.

What you're probably missing is that, in your case, `bar` is always an object of form `{ chart : {} }`. Long story short, every iteration of `.each()` is overwriting the previous `$.extend()` call.

Through the first iteration, `opts.chartOptions` will be extended with `opts.chartOptions.chart`, which is calculated from the first `div` in your `.each()` context.

Through the second iteration, you'll be trying to extend `opts.chartOptions` again with `opts.chartOptions.chart`, **which it already has**. But jQuery doesn't care, so it'll assign the second `div`'s calculated values to the first `div`'s values in `opts.chartOptions.chart`.

And so on, and so forth.

While in the way you're using it here, it *normally* shouldn't matter, it does here because you're using the value of `opts.chartOptions` in your AJAX's callback function. This creates a **closure** on `opts.chartOptions`, which means that by the time your AJAX's callback fires, its value may not be what you'd expect (because it might have been modified by another iteration of `.each()`, blah blah).

**WHEW!!**